# Radio Button not firing itemcommand event in repeater

Tags: asp.net, gridview, radio-button, custom-controls

I am working on the `asp.net` `custom control` in which I am using `repeater control` to show `radio buttons`.
I need to fire repeaters `ItemCommand event` when `RadioButton` is click.
The problem I faced is `RadioButton` is not capabel of firing `ItemCommend event` and it does not have `CommendArgument`, and `CommandName` properties.
To accomplish I created `asp.net server control`, drived i from `RadioButton` and add `CommendArgument`, and `CommandName` properties in it.

I also added a `Button` in it so that I can call the click event of this `button` programatically to fire repeaters `ItemCommand event`.
Now the problem I am facing is I have fired `Button's click` event but still `ItemCommand` event is not firing.
Any idea how to gat this thind done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the repeaters `ItemCommand` event when the `OnCheckedChanged` of the radio button is fired.

I think the main problem is you're not sure how to create the arguments expected by `ItemCommand`, here's an example which I believe will help:

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptColors" runat="server" onitemcommand="rptColors_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbColour" Text='<%# Eval("Color") %>' AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="Checked" /> <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public class Colours
{
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            rptColors.DataSource = new List<Colours> { new Colours { Color = "Red" }, new Colours { Color = "Black" } };
            rptColors.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptColors.Items)
        {
            RadioButton rdbColour = item.FindControl("rdbColour") as RadioButton;
            if (rdbColour.Text.Equals((sender as RadioButton).Text))
            {
                CommandEventArgs commandArgs = new CommandEventArgs("SomeCommand", rdbColour.Text);
                RepeaterCommandEventArgs repeaterArgs = new RepeaterCommandEventArgs(item, rdbColour, commandArgs);
                rptColors_ItemCommand(rdbColour, repeaterArgs);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void rptColors_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        //Runs when you select the radio button in the repeater
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

Comment: which event should be used for radiobuttonlist.

Comment: The one that fires when you click the radio button