# How to get row index from object sender, EventArgs e

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DataList on a asp.net page. On each row of the datalist I have two radio buttons (not radiobuttonlist). Depending of the radio button pressed they enable some textboxes on the same row and show some information. Both radio buttons are tied to the same event handler.

My question is, how can I know the row number (index) of the DataList were the Radio buttons were pressed?

This is my code of the event handler of the radio buttons:

```
    protected void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        try
        {               
            RadioButton radioBtn = (RadioButton)sender;     
            if (radioBtn.Checked == true)
            {
                switch (radioBtn.ID)
                {
                    case "RadioButton1":
                        //Enable some textboxes
                        //Show some info - Need to display the row number of the Datalist where the Radio buttons were pressed
                        break;

                    case "RadioButton2":
                        //Disable some texboxes
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Assuming you create the radio buttons dynamically, you could define row numbers and add it to the ID (e.g. "RadioButton0", "RadioButton1", "RadioButton2", etc.)

Comment: Potentially useful answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972749/radio-button-not-firing-itemcommand-event-in-repeater

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the NamingContainer to get the parent control and get it's item index.

```
protected void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataListItem item = (DataListItem)((RadioButtonList)sender).NamingContainer;

    Label1.Text = item.ItemIndex.ToString();
}
```